# "Correct" way to playback user movement with xlib?

Tags: user-interface, unix, xlib

I'm trying to figure out a way to make demos for a program I've written with xlib, and I came across [this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xtestfakekeyevent), but, according to the author page:

`This extension is not intended to support general journaling and playback of user actions.`

Does anyone know of any functions in xlib that are intended to support playback of user actions? Does it even exist? Or could I just use this without any real problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fake input with Xtest and record events with the record extension.

http://www.x.org/docs/Xext/xtest.pdf

http://www.xfree86.org/current/recordlib.pdf